# has a file changed of value

Tags: linux, files, python, stdout

im trying to use pyinotify to detect if a file has changed.

managed to do it this way

```
def status(argument):
    global email_alarm_status
    global new_email_alarm

    if not email_alarm_status:
        with open('pathtofile') as fp:
            email_alarm_status = fp.read()
        with open("pathtofile","w") as cp:
            cp.write(email_alarm_status)

    with open('pathtofile') as fp:
        with open("pathtofile") as cp:
            if cp.read() != fp.read():
                print "changed"
                email_alarm_status = fp.read()


wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
wm.add_watch('pathtofile', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY)   
notifier.loop(callback=status)
```

this will "notify" when value changed. now the issue is that notifier.loop print the information about the event, have tried "to shut it up" trying to turn stdout for a bit with:

```
class NullDevice():
    def write(self, s):
        pass

original_stdout = sys.stdout  # keep a reference to STDOUT
sys.stdout = NullDevice()  # redirect the real STDOUT
print "2 - this won't print"
sys.stdout = original_stdout  # turn STDOUT back on
print "3 - this will print to SDTDOUT"
wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
wm.add_watch('/home/pi/socketserver/var', pyinotify.IN_MODIFY)
sys.stdout = f

notifier.loop(callback=status)

sys.stdout = original_stdout  # turn STDOUT back on
print "3 - this will print to SDTDOUT"
```

but it wont work, it returns an error from pyinotify...

```
pi@TestEnv:~ $ python ./python/handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python/handler", line 83, in <module>
    notifier.loop(callback=status)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 1390, in loop
    self.process_events()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 1287, in process_events
    self._default_proc_fun(revent)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 924, in __call__
    return _ProcessEvent.__call__(self, event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 650, in __call__
    return self.process_default(event)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyinotify.py", line 982, in process_default
    self._out.flush()
AttributeError: NullDevice instance has no attribute 'flush'
```

would anyone know why this is? alternatively any way to implement a if file has changed functionality?

Comment: I think this is a better fit for http://stackoverflow.com/ than here, but I answered this question nonetheless.

Comment: im banned from so for the time being, thanks for answering...

Comment: Posting the question on Unix stackexchange when it belongs on stackoverflow to get around a ban 1) is kind of unethical, 2) doesn't make the question any more on-topic. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create your notifier:

```
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm)
```

you can pass a second parameter that handles the event. By default the handler prints the event. To stop this create your own minimal handler that does nothing. Eg:

```
class NoLog(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):
    def process_default(self, event):
        pass

handler = NoLog()
notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, default_proc_fun=handler)
```

See [handling events](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify/wiki/Handling-Events)

Comment: I'll give it a try sound even better. Thanks.

Comment: This worked for me, and it actually a better fit, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify sys.stdout like that; sys.stdout is just a [TextIOWrapper](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper) around real standard output, which is actually file descriptor 1. The result is that things like `print` (or anything that writes to file descriptor 1 directly) will totally ignore what you've done. In order to achieve true redirection, you have to do something like this:

```
# Copy standard out to a second file descriptor for restoration
original_stdout = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())

# Replace standard out with /dev/null
nullfd = os.open("/dev/null", os.O_WRONLY)
os.dup2(nullfd, sys.stdout.fileno())
os.close(nullfd)

# Do your stuff here

# Restore standard out and close duplicated file descriptor
os.dup2(original_stdout, sys.stdout.fileno())
os.close(original_stdout)
```

This will then redirect all of standard out to /dev/null, and then restore it again after you're done. See [the docs on os.dup](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup), [os.dup2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.dup2) and [this StackOverflow post about redirecting standard file descriptors in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14543484/5808767) (the same principle applies to Python).

Note, you must use the `os` functions here, not the built-in `open`. You must work with the actual underlying file descriptors for this to work.